# How to display an image with MvxImageView into a MvxListView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a MvxListView in Xamarin.Android app, and an ItemTemplate to display a name and a picture retrieve from WS. If the name is displayed, it is not the case of the picture ...

View_Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00007f"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ItemsModels"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

item_list.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have the internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml, and I installed DownloadCache and File plugins.

Urls are good, I display them in Visual Studio Console and when I click on them, image display.

I followed this video to try to display image, but I don't know why it works for him and not for me ...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBzj_nkeLFI

Maybe because he uses MvvmCross 3.0 and I'm using MvvmCross 4.0 ...

**FIRST EDIT**

My ItemModel class

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsFavorite { get; set; }
}
```

and a typical value of Image property : http://inu.tapptic.com/test/image.php?text=%E5%8D%81%E5%85%AB

The problem is not the URL, I tried with a URL found on google image, and it doesn't work too

**SECOND EDIT**

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IDataProviderService _dataProviderService;

    #region Fields

    private ObservableCollection<ItemModel> _itemsModels;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> ItemsModels
    {
        get { return _itemsModels; }
        set
        {
            _itemsModels = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ItemsModels);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public MainViewModel(IDataProviderService dataProviderService)
    {
        _dataProviderService = dataProviderService;
    }

    #endregion

    public override void Start()
    {
        TimeWatcher.BeforeExecution();
        Task.Run(() => LoadData()); // A voir car ça lance un autre "faux thread", mais ça bloque pas l'UI
        base.Start();
        TimeWatcher.ExecutionEnd();
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        ItemsModels = await _dataProviderService.GetItemsAsync("http://dev.tapptic.com/", "test/json.php");

        // Just to see if URLs are good
        foreach(var itemsModel in ItemsModels)
            Debug.WriteLine(itemsModel.Image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your Item ViewModel and one example of the Image property value?

Comment: Is the Image property set, before it is bound or do you change this property after the databinding? If you change it after the binding, you need to implement `INoftifyPropertyChanged`and invoke the delegate. Have you had a look at hte debug otuput? MvvmCross usually writes trace messages, if something goes wrong.

Comment: I don't know if it's before or after the databinding ... (I'm so newbie with this libs ...) but to be sure, I implemented now INotifyPropertyChanged, and nothing changed

Comment: in wich project did you install the download plugin? You have to install it in your android project. If this is not the problem: could you pls post your main viewmodel that contains `ItemsModels` and creates the items!?

Comment: Yes, I installed in Android project. I added my MainViewModel class in "Second edit"

Comment: I can't reproduce it. You killed all my ideas ^^ Its even working in my test application. Have you got a sample application somewhere?

Comment: You need to install DownloadCache, File and Json plugins on both the Core and Droid project